# facing a problem while installing latex from terminal

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, latex

i am new to Ubuntu and have Ubuntu 14.04.02 installed on my computer. I wanted to install the latest latex and so I downloaded and extracted the file from `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` and according to instructions given [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

I wrote the command `./install-tl` and after that wrote `i` for installing latex on harddisk.but it was showing

```
./install-tl: mkdir(/usr/local/texlive/) failed, goodbye: Permission denied
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using administration rights via `sudo`

```
sudo ./install-tl
```

---

You could also install `texlive-full` or `texlive` via the package manager by:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

or:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

Comment: I see two problems here.  
1. The TeXLive team doesn't recommend using `sudo`.  
2. Installing `texlive` via `apt` is not recommended. `apt` often has older versions of texlive which may create problems in the future.

Answer (score 6):

@nikhilweee is right. Don't use `sudo`.

TeXLive installation scripts cannot cater to the myriad of folder structures and permissions.

## When you have access to `sudo`

The best installation method is the official method. Stay with the official folder location `/usr/local` by doing a `cd /usr/local` then a `` sudo mkdir texlive && sudo chown `whoami` texlive ``.

The `install-tl` script will then run without a hitch.

Staying with the default folder location lets you write documentation and instructions (for your team) easier. The official guides for TeXLive uses that folder location, so your team can get some self-help browsing those guides themselves. Also, 3rd-party packages (like Atom editor) can be easily configured given standard TeX Live folder locations.

## When you have no access to `sudo`

See answer from @PHPirate at [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110184/915514).

Answer (score 1):

As [@nikhilweee already mentions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657535/facing-a-problem-while-installing-latex-from-terminal#comment1643440_657548), sometimes you cannot or do not want to use `sudo`, so you want to install to your users' directory. There are at least two ways you can go about this.

1. You can set the following environment variables,

as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29784261/4126843):

```
export TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/your_user/texlive
export TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXDIR=/home/your_user/texlive/2018
```

and then install with `./install-tl`.

2. You can use a `texlive.profile` file for installation and change all the `/usr/local` paths to `/home/your_user`, then install with `./install-tl --profile=texlive.profile`.